# Strings not displayed right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, puts

So, I have this which displays emails to a user.

OLD CODE FOR REFERENCE:

```
<%= for email in @emails 
    # print the name
    eml = email
    eml 
    puts "<br>"
end
%>
```

FIXED, WORKING, STABLE CODE:

```
<% for email in @emails  %>
    <%= email %>
    <br>
<% end %>
<%= puts @emails.inspect %>
```

As you can see, it was a problem of multiple line tag. Bazar that It would cause this problem, but not at all that it would cause A problem.

OLD:

And it is working great. One thing. So, EML is a ruby string with `HIDDEN@HIDDEN.HIDDEN`, but when it goes to display I get this on the rendered page: `["HIDDEN@HIDDEN.HIDDEN"]`, so why is it doing that? Inspected it, it isn't a hash. Just a string. What is happening here?

Comment: Are you certain it's just a string, and not an array of 1-element arrays?  `puts @emails.inspect` or `eml.class`

Comment: ["HIDDEN@HIDDEN.HIDDEN"] is the exact inspected result. No class type or anything. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: That's all you have in `@emails`, just the one element array? That doesn't make sense. Check both `@emails.class` and `eml.class`.

Comment: Wait, your comment changed. Is that `@emails` or `eml` in your last comment? That's definitely an array.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Can a single ERB tag really span lines as shown in the OP's view fragment?

Comment: @emails.class is Array, eml.class doesn't give me anything. Bazar

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I wasn't even noticing the ERB around that, and thinking it was console code.

Comment: In that comment @MichaelBerkowski, it is @ emails, and EML.class returns nothing.

Comment: Is this in a Rails project? Is it an `.html.erb` file? People are just going to be guessing at answers unless you expand your question to include some background information. Who up-voted such a question?

Answer (score 4):

This syntax does not look quite right.  If this is being rendered in a view using ERB, you probably want code that looks more like this:

```
<% @emails.each do |email| %>
    <%= email %><br />
<% end %>
```

The way you have that written is very C#-looking. In Ruby it is more common to use the methods attached to the object. Enumerable objects like arrays could be iterated through using the each method and a special structure in Ruby called a block.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each

Comment: Ruby is ruby. It isn't a strict syntax. That code made NO difference.

Comment: Also, I've never used C#, and I haven't used C for more than just Input and Output.

Comment: What's going on is that in your <%= %> ERB tag you are telling it to display the output of that expression. What's its doing is displaying the value returned by the "for" loop, which in this case is the array you passed to it. If you want to print the "eml" value followed by a <br> tag, you need to isolate that in its own <%= %>. The puts its outputting the string "<br>" to the console and not the web page.